# cocoa - comparing dates, warning passing argument one of 'compare:' from distinctive objective-c type

Tags: cocoa, date, compare

I've had a look through similar queries on here and elsewhere but i still can't seem to resolve my problem.

I am trying to see whether a date stored in a mutable dictionary in an array is between two other dates. The piece of code generating the warning is:

```
if ( [[[records objectAtIndex:( i )] objectForKey:@"Date"] compare:userStartDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [[[records objectAtIndex:( i )] objectForKey:@"Date"] compare:userEndDate] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
```

As it may be relevant, userStartDate is created as follows:

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)newRecords andWithUserStartDate:(NSDate *)newUserStartDate andWithUserEndDate:(NSDate *)newUserEndDate {
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self setRecords:newRecords];
    [self setUserStartDate:newUserStartDate];
    [self setUserEndDate:newUserEndDate];
}
return self;
```

}

Called from another part of code by:

```
summariser = [[Summariser alloc]initWithArray:records andWithUserStartDate:[userTimesStartDatePicker dateValue] andWithUserEndDate:[userTimesEndDatePicker dateValue]];
```

And the record itself as:

```
[record setObject:[datePicker dateValue] forKey:@"Date"];
```

I hope this is clear and that someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `userStartDate`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `objectForKey:` returns `id`, so the compiler can't be sure it's an instance of `NSDate` and triggers the warning.

Comment: That would be a different warning, though.